# python pyglet on_mouse_press

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm trying to make a simple GUI using pyglet.

**Here is my code:**

```
button_texture = pyglet.image.load('button.png')
button = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(button_texture, x=135, y=window.height-65)

def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
   if x > button and x < (button + button_texture.width):
      if y > button and y < (button + button_texture.height):
         run_program()
```

[image]

**The problem**

The "button.png" is displayed as the red box with "Click" inside. and is supposed to start run_program(). But currently the yellow in the bottom left is the place i have to click to initiate run_program().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the button (the key-code) with the X/Y coordinates. This happens, because the function parameter `button` shadows your global variable. Also, you should use the buttons `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` attributes.

```
button_texture = pyglet.image.load('button.png')
button_sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(button_texture, x=135, y=window.height-65)

def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
   if x > button_sprite.x and x < (button_sprite.x + button_sprite.width):
      if y > button_sprite.y and y < (button_sprite.y + button_sprite.height):
         run_program()
```

I renamed your global variable `button` with `button_sprite` to avoid the name collision.